# Not equal string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to set a condition like this

```
if (myString=!"-1")
{
  //Do things
}
```

But it fails. I've tried

```
if(myString.Distinct("-1")) 
{
  //Do things
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Use `Equals`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx

Comment: This is your answer: `if (!myString.Equals("-1"))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be this:

```
if (myString != "-1")
{
    //Do things
}
```

Your equals and exclamation are the wrong way round.

Comment: Well spotted! One of those situations where an error message might have been nice.

Comment: On C# 7.5 the != operator did not work. .Equals did the job for me.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
if(myString != "-1")
```

The opperand is `!=` and not `=!`

You can also use `Equals`

```
if(!myString.Equals("-1"))
```

Note the `!` before myString

Comment: `if(!myString.Equals("-1"))` is very useful in case of bool result is needed

Answer (score 1):

With `Equals()` you can also use a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions):

```
if ( ! "-1".Equals(myString) )
```

Comment: Worked great in C# 7.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now in C# 9, it can be done in a more readable way like this.

```
string  str = "x";
if(str is not "y")
{
    ...
}
```